# Grep for multiple patterns in a folder containing n number of files.And if a match found for patterns create mkdir

Tags: regex, linux, bash, python-2.7, scripting

Can we grep for multiple patterns in a folder containing n number of files. And if a match found for each and every pattern create a directory and push the files of similar pattern type into same directory likewise the others.

For example : I am having a folder name : `X`. `X` can have multiple sub folders and multiple files inside them.

I want to search for a pattern like `This code is from`. If a match of this string is found in multiple files in `X` folder create a directory named `dir1` and push all the matched files into `dir1`.

And the same for other patterns matches also if the matches are found create directories and push the files into respective directories.

I tried of searching with grep can found all pattern matched files but parallely I can't do `mkdir` . In this way for n matches of patterns in `X` n dir it should create. Searching is fine but having issue with directories creation parallely.

Comment: See - http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Ok this is the part 
mkdir dir;grep -irl "Version" | xargs cp -t dir/
I can able to create a directory and push all the files which matches the text here iam getting an error like cp: will not overwrite just-create.
And in my case i want the same folder structure with the file to be copied inside that directory.

Answer (score 0):

one way to get the same folder structure is, unfortunately, not to use `xargs cp -t dir`, but instead copy one-by-one with rsync, e.g.,

```
grep -irl "Version" | xargs -I{} rsync -a "{}" "dir/{}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I mean, it's not elegant, but you could use embedded for loops with an array of search strings.

EDIT: Missed the part about separate folders for different match strings. Changes are below.

```
#!/bin/bash
#Assuming:
#patarr is an array containing all paterns
#test/files is the location of files to be searched
#test/found is the location of matching files

for file in test/files/* #*/
#This loop runs for every file in test/files/. $file holds the filename of the current file
do
    for ((i=0;i<${#patarr[@]};i++))
    #This loop runs once for every index in the patarr array. $i holds the current loop number
    do
        if [[ $(cat $file | grep ${patarr[$i]} | wc -l) -gt 0 ]]
        #if grep finds at least one match using the pattern in patarr with index "i"
        then
            #cp $file temp/found/ #Old code, see edit above
            mkdir -p temp/found/${pararr[$i]}
            #Makes a folder with the name as our search string. -p means no error if the folder already exists.
            cp $file temp/found/${pararr[$i]}/
            #Copies the file into said folder
        fi
    done
done
```